# thrift cpp sample code compile error

Tags: c++, reference, client, thrift

I'm new to Thrift.
I think I installed it correctly. I have the folowing libs :

```
luckyan315@ubuntu:~/code/thrift-0.8.0/tutorial/cpp$ ll /usr/local/lib/

total 11496
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Mar 23 19:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Oct 12 22:27 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4100463 Mar 31 20:26 libthrift-0.8.0.so*
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7256552 Mar 31 20:26 libthrift.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      991 Mar 31 20:26 libthrift.la*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       18 Mar 23 19:35 libthrift.so -> libthrift-0.8.0.so*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   160727 Mar 31 20:26 libthriftz-0.8.0.so*
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   218290 Mar 31 20:26 libthriftz.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      998 Mar 31 20:26 libthriftz.la*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 Mar 23 19:35 libthriftz.so -> libthriftz-0.8.0.so*
```

Then I tryed to compile the cppClient tutorial but I have "undefined 
reference" errors as follows:

```
luckyan315@ubuntu:~/code/thrift-0.8.0/tutorial/cpp$ sudo g++ -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -o Server -I/usr/local/include/thrift/ -I/usr/local/boost/include/boost-1_33_1/  -I../gen-cpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -lthrift CppServer.cpp ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `main':
CppServer.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::transport::TServerSocket::TServerSocket(int)'
CppServer.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer::serve()'
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer::~TSimpleServer()':
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift6server13TSimpleServerD2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift6server13TSimpleServerD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer'
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `apache::thrift::transport::TBufferedTransport::TBufferedTransport(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>)':
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport18TBufferedTransportC2EN5boost10shared_ptrINS1_10TTransportEEE[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport18TBufferedTransportC5EN5boost10shared_ptrINS1_10TTransportEEE]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TBufferedTransport'
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer::TSimpleServer<apache::thrift::TProcessor>(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::TProcessor> const&, boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TServerTransport> const&, boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransportFactory> const&, boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory> const&, boost::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<apache::thrift::TProcessor*, apache::thrift::TProcessor*>::type, void*>::type)':
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift6server13TSimpleServerC2INS0_10TProcessorEEERKN5boost10shared_ptrIT_EERKNS6_INS0_9transport16TServerTransportEEERKNS6_INSB_17TTransportFactoryEEERKNS6_INS0_8protocol16TProtocolFactoryEEENS5_9enable_ifINS5_14is_convertibleIPS7_PS4_E4typeEPvE4typeE[_ZN6apache6thrift6server13TSimpleServerC5INS0_10TProcessorEEERKN5boost10shared_ptrIT_EERKNS6_INS0_9transport16TServerTransportEEERKNS6_INSB_17TTransportFactoryEEERKNS6_INS0_8protocol16TProtocolFactoryEEENS5_9enable_ifINS5_14is_convertibleIPS7_PS4_E4typeEPvE4typeE]+0x3a): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer'
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::writeMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType, int)':
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE17writeMessageBeginERKSsNS1_12TMessageTypeEi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::writeMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType, int)]+0x15): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_1'
/tmp/cc7lnwSw.o: In function `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)':
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE16readMessageBeginERSsRNS1_12TMessageTypeERi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)]+0x33): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_MASK'
CppServer.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE16readMessageBeginERSsRNS1_12TMessageTypeERi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)]+0x3d): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_1'
/tmp/ccBkDvwC.o: In function `shared::SharedServiceClient::recv_getStruct(shared::SharedStruct&)':
SharedService.cpp:(.text+0x6f3): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)'
/tmp/ccBkDvwC.o: In function `shared::SharedServiceProcessor::process(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, void*)':
SharedService.cpp:(.text+0xb05): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccBkDvwC.o: In function `shared::SharedServiceProcessor::process_fn(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int, void*)':
SharedService.cpp:(.text+0xd87): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccBkDvwC.o: In function `shared::SharedServiceProcessor::process_getStruct(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)':
SharedService.cpp:(.text+0x1409): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorClient::recv_ping()':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x12af): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorClient::recv_add()':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x173b): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorClient::recv_calculate()':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x1c7b): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorProcessor::process(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, void*)':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x227f): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorProcessor::process_ping(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x298e): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorProcessor::process_add(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x2f9b): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/tmp/ccLRxoVZ.o: In function `tutorial::CalculatorProcessor::process_calculate(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)':
Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x3609): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: My command is :
sudo g++ -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -o Server -I/usr/local/include/thrift/ -I/usr/local/boost/include/boost-1_33_1/  -I../gen-cpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -lthrift CppServer.cpp ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp

Comment: why are you calling g++ as root? try without, but try running ldconfig (as root) first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The -lthrift option should be at the end of the command line, after the cpp files.

I've compiled successfully the sample on Ubuntu 11.10/gcc 4.6.1/boost 1.49 with the following makefile:

```
THRIFT_VER =thrift-0.8.0
USR_DIR    =${HOME}/usr
THRIFT_DIR =${USR_DIR}/${THRIFT_VER}
INCS_DIRS  =-I${USR_DIR}/include -I${THRIFT_DIR}/include/thrift
LIBS_DIRS  =-L${USR_DIR}/lib -L${USR_DIR}/${THRIFT_VER}/lib
CPP_DEFS   =-D=HAVE_CONFIG_H
CPP_OPTS   =-Wall -O2
LIBS       =-lthrift

GEN_SRC    = ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp  \
             ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp   \
             ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp \
             ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp
GEN_INC    = -I../gen-cpp

default: server client

server: CppServer.cpp
    g++ ${CPP_OPTS} ${CPP_DEFS} -o CppServer ${GEN_INC} ${INCS_DIRS} CppServer.cpp ${GEN_SRC} ${LIBS_DIRS} ${LIBS}

client: CppClient.cpp
    g++ ${CPP_OPTS} ${CPP_DEFS} -o CppClient ${GEN_INC} ${INCS_DIRS} CppClient.cpp ${GEN_SRC} ${LIBS_DIRS} ${LIBS}

clean:
    $(RM) -r CppClient CppServer
```

Take care to put tabs at the beginning of the make commands.

My layout is:

> boost 1.49 installed in ${HOME}/usr
>   boost headers in ${HOME}/usr/include
>   boost libs in ${HOME}/usr/lib
>
> thrift 0.8.0 installed in ${HOME}/usr/thrift-0.8.0
>   thrift headers in ${HOME}/usr/thrift-0.8.0/include
>   thrift libs in ${HOME}/usr/thrift-0.8.0/lib

To run the samples:

```
#!/bin/bash
THRIFT_VER=thrift-0.8.0
USR_DIR=${HOME}/usr
THRIFT_DIR=${USR_DIR}/${THRIFT_VER}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${THRIFT_DIR}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
exec $1
```

Comment: change "CPP_DEFS   =-D=HAVE_CONFIG_H" to "CPP_DEFS   =-D=HAVE_NETINET_IN_H  " in my case.

Comment: why does  `-lthrift` has to at the end of the line ? It works.

Answer (score 1):

Add following compilation option

```
-std=c++11
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

after some search I might find the reason...It's because your g++'s version...
in short, the working gcc are:

> g++ 4.4.6: OK
>   g++ 4.5.3: OK
>   g++ 4.6.1: complains about undefined reference to

links:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201107.mbox/%3C4E321FD6.4090503@verizon.net%3E

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-dev/201107.mbox/%3C4E3161D1.3090509@ens-lyon.fr%3E

Comment: Yeah, you're right , g++ 4.6.1 have to add -O1 or -O2 arguments, I use josendf's Makefile, resolved all the problem, thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for Os X.

First install the dependencies and thrift itself, easiest to do with [brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install boost
brew install thrift
```

Note that if you've already tried to install thrift manually you may have to uninstall it first.

[Download thrift](https://web.archive.org/web/20211022045657/http://thrift.apache.org/download) and compile the tutorial:

```
cd ./thrift-0.8.0/tutorial
thrift --gen cpp ./tutorial.thrift
cd ./cpp
```

Replace the existing Makefile with following (based on jedf solution):

```
THRIFT_VER =thrift/0.8.0
USR_DIR    =/usr/local/Cellar
THRIFT_DIR =${USR_DIR}/${THRIFT_VER}
INCS_DIRS  =-I${USR_DIR}/include -I${THRIFT_DIR}/include/thrift -I${USR_DIR}/boost/1.49.0/include/boost
LIBS_DIRS  =-L${USR_DIR}/${THRIFT_VER}/lib
CPP_DEFS   =-D=HAVE_CONFIG_H
CPP_OPTS   =-Wall -O2
LIBS       =-lthrift

GEN_SRC    = ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp  \
             ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp   \
             ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp \
             ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp
GEN_INC    = -I../gen-cpp

default: server client

server: CppServer.cpp
        g++ ${CPP_OPTS} ${CPP_DEFS} -o CppServer ${GEN_INC} ${INCS_DIRS} CppServer.cpp ${GEN_SRC} ${LIBS_DIRS} ${LIBS}

client: CppClient.cpp
        g++ ${CPP_OPTS} ${CPP_DEFS} -o CppClient ${GEN_INC} ${INCS_DIRS} CppClient.cpp ${GEN_SRC} ${LIBS_DIRS} ${LIBS}

clean:
        $(RM) -r CppClient CppServer
```

Compile:

```
make
```

Run the server and the client:

```
./CppServer
./CppClient
```

In addition, whenever you need to compile third party code that requires thrift use the following:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.8.0/lib/pkgconfig/
```